# CriteriaBuilder Cannot resolve method 'greaterThan(int, int)'

Tags: java, jpa, criteria

I'm forming a query where I'm comparing the db result with API request data, but i'm getting below error:

Cannot resolve method 'greaterThan(int, int)'.

My code looks something like below. 2 is coming from the API request.

```
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(myFunc(root.get("amt")),2));
```

Basically myFunc function would multiply root.get("amt") with some number based on some condition. but this is not working for me as both expressions are of type "int" and it does not expect that.
How to form specification in this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature for `greaterThan` is:

```
<Y extends Comparable<? super Y>> Predicate 
greaterThan(Expression<? extends Y> x, Expression<? extends Y> y)
```

In other words, it takes arguments that are `Expression` objects whose value type (`Y`) implements `Comparable<? extends Y>`.  Java doesn't know how to convert two integers into two `Expression` objects.  (In fact, I can't think of any PL that would be able to do *that* conversion without you saying what *kind* of `Expression` you need there.)

However, if you look at the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee%2F7%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html) for `CriteriaBuilder` you will also see some `gt` methods that create `Predicate` objects to compare `Number` instances.  So the following ought to work:

```
predicates.add(
    criteriaBuilder.gt(
        Integer.valueOf(myFunc(root.get("amt"))),
        Integer.valueOf(2)));
```

**CORRECTION**

```
predicates.add(
    criteriaBuilder.gt(
        criteriaBuilder.literal(
            Integer.valueOf(myFunc(root.get("amt")))),
        Integer.valueOf(2)));
```

because the first argument of `gt` needs to be an expression too.

Comment: No its giving the same error, this time with Integer. Cannot resolve method 'lessThan(Integer, Integer)'. I tried this:- Predicate tryp = criteriaBuilder.gt(Integer.valueOf(1),Integer.valueOf(2));

Comment: Use `lt` instead of `lessThan`.  Read the javadocs.  And read the compilation errors carefully.   That message says "lessThan" not "gt". (If I had a long-handled clue-stick, I'd dong you on the head with it. Sheesh!)

Comment: Sorry I pasted wrong code. It is :- Predicate tryp = criteriaBuilder.lt(Integer.valueOf(1),Integer.valueOf(2)); and the error is Cannot resolve method 'lessThan(Integer, Integer)'

Comment: I dont know if you have tried your solution or not but for me it does not work and as you said as per JavaDoc the cb.gt / cb.lt expects either (Expression<? extends Number> x,Number y) or (Expression<? extends Number> x, Expression<? extends Number>) hence the solution you shared which is making both x and y as Integer can not happen. you can try doing   criteriaBuilder.lt(Integer.valueOf(1),Integer.valueOf(2)); It will throw compilation error. Since its a query formation we ought to have a expression and myFunc(root.get("amt")) is not a expression.

Comment: See the update.

Answer (score 0):

GreaterThan or gt or LessThan or lt expects either (Expression<? extends Y> x,Y y) or (Expression<? extends Y> x, Expression<? extends Y> y).

So particularly when two integers are to be compared either of input to these criteriaBuilder method has to be a expression whose Object is same as the object of other input.
Below is the code which worked for me:

```
Expression<Integer> expr1 = 
criteriaBuilder.selectCase(root.get("amt"))
.when(1,10) /* this could be your any business logic, it is what myFunc was doing */
.when(2,20).as(Integer.class);
Integer expr2 = 15;
Predicate predicates = criteriaBuilder.lessThan(expr1,expr2);
```